# OData JSON Batching returning 200 ok with empty response

Tags: json, rest, odata

have been desperately trying to get the OData patching to work in Json format. My format looks like this

```
    {
  "requests": [
    {
      "atomicityGroup": "g1",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true",
        "odata-version": "4.0"
      },
      "method": "DELETE",
      "id": "1",
      "url": "ENTITY-1(GUID-ID)"
    },
    {
      "atomicityGroup": "g1",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true",
        "odata-version": "4.0"
      },
      "method": "DELETE",
      "id": "2",
      "url": "ENTITY-1(GUID-ID)"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I have been `POST`ing using main url say `"https:DOMAIN/api/data/v9.1/$batch"` with header in the request eneity containing `Content-Type:"multipart/mixed; boundary=g1"` before sending via `restTemplate.exchange`.

I am receiving a 200 OK with empty response and the two delete operations doesn't go through. I must say I have tried and tested the same thing in text format and it works fine. But Cant seem to get the JSON working. Any recommendation, advise/help would be highly appreciated. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: A 200 response simply says that the server received your POST, but it doesn't mean that it should respond with JSON. Do you have control over the API server? If not, what documentation is there?

Comment: Thanks. two main documentation that I followed (for json) can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/odatalib/json-batch
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching#code-try-0

Comment: Is your issue with understanding the formats of JSON, or is it about receiving data from the server? I thought you didn't receive data at all, and so my question was about documentation from your provider (server).

Comment: Primarily the json format and seeking advise from experts out there if there is any issue with the json i am trying to work with. If not then I know I will definitely have to go through other server.